# Formik validate number of uploaded forms reactjs

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, formik

I want to validate number of uploaded forms. If user uploads less than 3 files, an invalid feedback will display after user clicks the submit button.

As far as I know, to count the number of uploaded files, I need to use `Array.from(e.target.files).length` to make a conditional statement `if (Array.from(e.target.files).length < 3)`

But how should I write that array and conditional statement inside formik's validate?

**File Upload Input**

```
<Form.Group as={Col} md="4">
                            <Form.Label>Upload Quotation</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                              id="quotation"
                              name="quotation"
                              type="file"
                              multiple
                              onChange={formik.handleChange}
                              value={formik.values.quotation}
                            />
                            {formik.errors.quotation ? (
                              <div>{formik.errors.quotation}</div>
                            ) : null}
                          </Form.Group>
```

**Validate**

```
const validate = (values) => {
    // const uploaded = [...uploadedFiles];
    const errors = {};
    if (!values.edd) {
      errors.edd = "Required";
    }

    if (!values.reason) {
      errors.reason = "Required";
    }

    if (!values.quotation) {
      errors.quotation = "Required";
      // } else if (number of files uploaded < 3){
      // console.log("files uploaded: ", //number of uploaded files)
      errors.quotation = "Please upload at least 3 quotations";
    }

    return errors;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the validation of the number of uploaded files in Formik, you can use the setFieldValue method to dynamically update the value of the quotation field when files are uploaded.

**File Upload Input**

```
 <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
    <Form.Group as={Col} md="4">
      <Form.Label>Upload Quotation</Form.Label>
       <Form.Control
        id="quotation"
        name="quotation"
        type="file"
        multiple
        onChange={handleFileChange}
        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
      />
        {formik.errors.quotation && formik.touched.quotation && (
          <div>{formik.errors.quotation}</div>
        )}
     </Form.Group>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

**Validate**

```
 const formik = useFormik({
   initialValues: {
    edd: '',
    reason: '',
    quotation: null,
  },
    validate,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
    // Your form submission logic here
     console.log(values);
     },
   });

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    formik.setFieldValue('quotation', event.currentTarget.files);
    formik.handleChange(event);
  };

  const validate = (values) => {
  const errors = {};

   if (!values.edd) {
    errors.edd = 'Required';
   }

   if (!values.reason) {
   errors.reason = 'Required';
  }

  if (!values.quotation || values.quotation.length < 3) {
   errors.quotation = 'Please upload at least 3 quotations';
  }

  return errors;
 };
```

The handleFileChange function is responsible for updating the quotation field's value and triggering the handleChange method from Formik.